# Mysql sort ort order confusion when given 2 things

Tags: mysql

I always used only 1 column in my sort criteria. So just wanted to know what happens when i give order by `id, name ASC`. Does it sort by name or id?.

Comment: pradeep just a basic thing have u searched or read any tutorial on google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

sort by id first. rows with the same id are then sorted by name

Answer (score 1):

It will sort by id first and then by name.

E.g. For the following table and query
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC, name, ASC
ID | Name
1 | A
2 | A
1 | B
2 | B

The output would be
1 | A
1 | B
2 | A
2 | B

Answer (score 1):

```
order by id [ASC by default], name ASC.
```

ORDER BY works by giving column list from left to right. ASC is by "default" .
So first ordered by id in ascending order and then by name in ascending order for same ID.